# Flash videos with steam app?

Tags: flash, steam

I get this messagge instead of the videos in steam 64 bits.

```
You need to have a specific Flash Player installed to view video content in Steam. Please follow these directions to get the right version for Steam. You will need this Flash player even if you already have the latest player for your default web browser.
```

I follow those steps and I open the .deb USC opens and shows me bad comments from other users about that package. I have no trouble with flash videos on Firefox and don't want to get any. Should I install that package anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, don't do that. You're not even following the steps as explained because the displayed options are not there.

Download [this package](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/completion/?installer=Flash_Player_11.2_for_other_Linux_%28.tar.gz%29_32-bit) (corresponds to *Flash Player 11.2 for other Linux (tar.gz, 32 bit)*) and extract the file `libflashplayer.so` into `~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/plugins/` directory (you will probably need to create the `plugins` directory).

Then restart Steam and the videos should start working.

Answer (score 1):

[Download Flash](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/completion/?installer=Flash_Player_11.2_for_other_Linux_%28.tar.gz%29_32-bit) and open it.

In a terminal, paste:

```
mkdir -p ~/.steam/bin32/plugins
xdg-open ~/.steam/bin32/plugins
```

Drag `libflashplayer.so` from Archive Manager to the nautilus window that just opened.

Finally, restart Steam and all should be good.  Welcome to Ubuntu!